# FunctionPoles with arbitrary undefined function

Tags: functions, symbolic, complex, assumptions

Good day everyone. I have very simple question about behaviour of the functions FunctionPoles, FunctionMeromorphic e.t.c. Can these functions work properly with undefined functions? For example when I wrote:

```
FunctionPoles[1/(k^2 + Subscript[\[Omega], 1]), Subscript[\[Omega], 1]]
```

I obtained

```
{{-k^2, 1}}
```

But If I try to insert an undefined function $B(k)$ like that:

```
FunctionPoles[1/(k^2 + B[k] + Subscript[\[Omega], 
   1]), Subscript[\[Omega], 1]]
```

Then I did not obtain expected result. I also tried use Assumptions option but alas have no success. Is there a way to make it work properly? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you expect as the output?

Comment: {{-k^2-B[k], 1}}

Comment: If you write `FunctionPoles[1/(B + k^2 + ω1), ω1]`, it returns `{{-B-k^2,1}}`.

Comment: Alas I need it to be of form B[k] because I have a lot of such expressions with B[k],B[q] and B[k-q]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a workaround

```
FunctionPoles[1/(k^2 + B + Subscript[\[Omega],1]), Subscript[\[Omega], 1]]/.B->B[k]
```

> `{{-k^2 - B[k], 1}}`

BTW, `FunctionSingularities[1/(k^2 + B[k] + Subscript[\[Omega],  1]), Subscript[\[Omega], 1]]` works well.

Comment: Seems like a proper solution. However, it is very sad that FunctionPoles behaves itself in such a strange manner. Anyway, thanks for the answer.